# Как правильно составить JPQL запрос для того, чтобы получить список тех объектов, у которых подходит userId

Tags: java, sql, jpql

На данный момент этот код выводит весь список

```
@NamedQuery(name = Meal.ALL_SORTED, query = "SELECT u FROM Meal u ORDER BY u.id DESC")
```

Если добавить ключевое слово WHERE и userId, то компилятор выдает ошибку **"Named parameter not bound : user_id"**

```
@NamedQuery(name = Meal.ALL_SORTED, query = "SELECT u FROM Meal u WHERE u.user.id=:user_id ORDER BY u.id DESC")
```

Где мне необходимо прописать этот userId, чтобы компилятор не ругался?

Вот код метода

```
@Override
public List<Meal> getAll(int userId) {
    return em.createNamedQuery(Meal.ALL_SORTED, Meal.class).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: покажите код метода, а не только аннотацию

Comment: Добавил код метода